# global variable in asp-net mvc views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my web application I placed the menu on a partial view and load it from the Site.Master.

Now imagine a gmail like scenario where on your menu you'll have an Inbox(n) item where n is the number of unreaded mails. Is there a clean way to pass the n variable to all of the views that use the Site.Master masterpage?

Something like:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Inbox - " + ViewData["n"], "Index", "Home") %>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Viewbag property on all views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308524/access-viewbag-property-on-all-views)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use child actions along with the [Html.Action and Html.RenderAction](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) helpers. So let's elaborate with an example.

As always you start with a view model that will represent the information you want to show on this particular view (or in this case partial view):

```
public class InboxViewModel
{
    public int NumberOfUnreadMails { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class InboxController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        InboxViewModel model = ... // Repository, DI into the controller, ...
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

then a corresponding view (`~/Views/Inbox/Index.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%: Html.ActionLink("Inbox - " + Model.NumberOfUnreadMails, "Index", "Home") %>
```

and finally embed this in your master page so that it is available on all views:

```
<div class="leftMenu">
    <% Html.RenderAction("Index", "Inbox"); %>
</div>
```

Comment: This works just great. Didn't knew about the RenderAction, only the RenderPartial. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

just define Global objects in _ViewStart.cshtml (views root folder), and use them all around views in project ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider keeping this in `ViewData[]`. This is how you can easily share data between different (partial) views.

Controller:

```
ViewData["UnreadMessages"] = "5";
```

All views can simply access this property.

Comment: The problem with this is that I have to set ViewData["UnreadMessages"] on all my actions. I was looking for a cleaner method.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it the way you did in the example, just tell it to make the value a string, since view data returns objects, just unbox the number as a string and then you could use it just like that

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Inbox - " +ViewData["n"].ToString(), "Index", "Home") %>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I have to set ViewData["UnreadMessages"] on all my actions. I was looking for a cleaner method